# FontFace api is not working what should i do?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to load google font from js but it is giving error

```
 (async function () {
        let font = new FontFace(
          "Source Code Pro",
          `url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@500&display=swap)`
        );

        let f = await font.load().catch(alert);//error
        document.fonts.add(f);
      })();
```

errorName:- NetworkError: A network error occurred.
forCreatingError:- past code in ur console
can anyone give me alternative?

output should be font object but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because the [URL](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source%20Code%20Pro:wght@500&display=swap) you're passing in isn't a font, it's a chunk of CSS.

Try using an actual font file, such as this one (extracted from that CSS:)

```
let font = new FontFace(
  "Source Code Pro",
  "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcecodepro/v22/HI_diYsKILxRpg3hIP6sJ7fM7PqPMcMnZFqUwX28DP6QtMRrSlcZZJmOpwVS.woff)"
);
```

Comment: can you pleasure check why it is giving difference console log when I am refreshing? link:-https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-glitter-3j8zqf?file=/src/App.js refresh 4-5 times

Comment: I'm seeing the same console log every time.  What are you seeing?

Comment: 0
: 
"Everything can be taken from a man but one thing: the last of "
1
: 
"the human freedoms-to choose one's attitude in any given set of"
2
: 
" circumstances."

Comment: Well, it looks like you have code in there that splits up the string based on the window size.  If you're getting different results sometimes it's because you've changed the size of the window.    If this is a problem for some reason, it should probably be its own separate question; it's not related to what you asked here.

Comment: okay sir (for fill the text limit )

Comment: hi sorry for disturbing again but can you look at code and see what can be wrong?

Comment: i am struggle from 2-3 days now (and they have limit for posting question)

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing is wrong.  Please try to be clearer? What is the problem you're struggling with?

Comment: i have used same function in my project which is not giving me same result as here even in same text it should give me same answer because I am using position absolute and nowrap property so why it is giving difference answer ? (if you noticed I already important that font in CSS )

Comment: It's different because the window size is different.  If that's not what you want, don't base the calculation on the size of the window.  I don't know what else to tell you, sorry.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4LCdadNTGyMwm2F9l0Q8X1VkNb-EXJm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you give me code sniped which tell me how many word one line can have?

Comment: We seem to be talking past one another here.  Please post this as a new question; whatever you're asking me now is not related to this question.

Comment: You've asked 1 question recently which has not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your question has received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.

It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 1 day before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments

Comment: they are not letting me